# Selenium does not use my custom profile in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am using selenium with chrome, but it does not use the profile that I specified, but starts with a new profile instead. Here is the python code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/username/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

The browser opens but it does not use my profile. The version of selenium is 3.5.0, the version of chrome driver is 2.31, the version of chrome is 60.0.3112.113, and I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

To find path to your chrome profile data you need to type chrome://version/ into address bar . For ex. mine is displayed as

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default,
```

to use it in the script I had to exclude

```
\Default\
```

so we end up with only

```
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data.
```

Also if you want to have separate profile just for selenium: replace the path with any other path and if it doesn't exist on start up chrome will create new profile and directory for it.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: I haven't checked this now, but i remember using the exact steps somewhere before and it worked for me. If possible, can you check it again please?

Comment: To select a different profile, say Profile 1, use

options.addArguments("profile-directory=Profile 1");